# Create a video in Matlab

Tags: options, programming

I'm studying these codes from Mathworks https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/plotting-sensitivities-of-an-option.html
The output is a 3D image. Is it possible to get a video that shows the creation of the mesh?

Comment: This *might* be possible using OBS (Open Broadcaster Software, or other video software) in conjunction with MATLAB. I haven't done it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I don'k know the software you tells me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another site, perhaps on https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask there.

Comment: The solution here might also help (using ffmpeg) -- if you can create a sequence of JPEGs named with consecutive integers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298100/creating-a-movie-from-a-series-of-plots-in-r